# ERROR importing sql database

Tags: mysql

I am a beginner with the sql databases. I am trying to import a database to phpmyadmin and I am getting an error saying:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DEFAULT_AUTOINCREMENT,
>       firstName varchar (30) NOT_NULL,
>       lastName var' at line 2

my sql code looks like that:

```
use myAddressBook
;

create table names (
    personID int DEFAULT_AUTOINCREMENT,
    firstName varchar (30) NOT_NULL,
    lastName varchar (30) NOT_NULL,
    constraint pk_name primary_key (personID)
) 
;
create table addresses (
    addressID int DEFAULT_AUTOINCREMENT,
        personID int NOT_NULL,
    address1 varchar (50),
    address2 varchar (50),
    city varchar (30),
    state varchar (2),
    zipcode varchar (10),
    constraint fk_addresses foreign_key (personID)
        references names (personID),
    constraint pk_addresses primary_key (addressID)
) 
;
create table phoneNumbers (
    phoneID int DEFAULT_AUTOINCREMENT,
        personID int NOT_NULL,
    phoneNumber varchar (20),
    constraint fk_phoneNumbers foreign_key (personID)
        references names (personID),
    constraint pk_phoneNumbers primary_key (phoneID)
) 
;
create table emailAddresses (
    emailID int DEFAULT_AUTOINCREMENT,
        personID int NOT_NULL,
    emailAddress varchar (50),
    constraint fk_emailAddresses foreign_key (personID)
        references names (personID),
    constraint pk_emailAddresses primary_key (emailID)
) 
;
```

Could anyone please point me in the right direction, where am I going wrong.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change all the `DEFAULT_AUTOINCREMENT` to `AUTO_INCREMENT` and all the `NOT_NULL` to `NOT NULL` and `primary_key` to `primary key` and `foreign_key` to `foreign key`

In general it is because the code does not match the syntax supported by MySQL.

Comment: have to wait another 5 minutes to be able to do so :)

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues with your code. You have to use correct MySQL key words instead :

```
        Wrong          |     Correct
=========================================
DEFAULT_AUTOINCREMENT ===> AUTO_INCREMENT
NOT_NULL              ===> NOT NULL
FOREIGN_KEY           ===> FOREIGN KEY
PRIMARY_KEY           ===> PRIMARY KEY
```

It should be like this :

```
USE myAddressBook
;

CREATE TABLE NAMES (
    personID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    firstName VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    lastName VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_name PRIMARY KEY (personID)
) 
;
CREATE TABLE addresses (
    addressID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
        personID INT NOT NULL,
    address1 VARCHAR (50),
    address2 VARCHAR (50),
    city VARCHAR (30),
    state VARCHAR (2),
    zipcode VARCHAR (10),
    CONSTRAINT fk_addresses FOREIGN KEY (personID)
        REFERENCES NAMES (personID),
    CONSTRAINT pk_addresses PRIMARY KEY (addressID)
) 
;
CREATE TABLE phoneNumbers (
    phoneID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
        personID INT NOT NULL,
    phoneNumber VARCHAR (20),
    CONSTRAINT fk_phoneNumbers FOREIGN KEY (personID)
        REFERENCES NAMES (personID),
    CONSTRAINT pk_phoneNumbers PRIMARY KEY (phoneID)
) 
;
CREATE TABLE emailAddresses (
    emailID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
        personID INT NOT NULL,
    emailAddress VARCHAR (50),
    CONSTRAINT fk_emailAddresses FOREIGN KEY (personID)
        REFERENCES NAMES (personID),
    CONSTRAINT pk_emailAddresses PRIMARY KEY (emailID)
) 
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in php but i also experience this kind of problem . what i did was :
1. export the tables using phpmyadmin.
2. copy the exported tables inside the c:\xampp\mysql\bin DIRECTORY
3. go to COMMAND PROMPT and type
4. cd\
5. cd c:\xampp\mysql\bin
6. execute this simple command
    mysql -u root -p newdatabase < names.sql

```
       note : newdatabase is DATABASE_NAME
              names.sql is table.sql that you exported from your database.
```

i hope it can help you.